# shows posts of only the logged in user

Tags: node.js, api, express, mongoose

I made a route to get posts of the logged in user but right now I'm getting posts of all the user when I call the api for this route. what shall I change here so that I get posts of that logged in user only instead of getting posts of all the users in the database?

route.js

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const posts = await Post.find().sort({ date: -1 });
      res.json(posts);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
  });
```

model schema of the posts

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema ({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    title:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    
    email: {
            type: String
    }
    ,
    age: [{
        type: String,
        required: true
       
    }],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
    
})

module.exports = Post = mongoose.model('post', PostSchema)
```

Comment: Add a parameter to your post retrieval that uniquely identifies the logged in user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a `filter` argument to the `find` method.

Assuming your `auth` middleware adds the authenticated user to the `req` object, line 3 of `route.js` should be:

```
      const posts = await Post.find({ user: req.user._id }).sort({ date: -1 });
```